# What are the differences between these usages of causative 'have'?

Tags: passive-voice, causative-have

Hello I would like an explanation on this usage of have as I believe it can be used as a passive, talking about things that have happened to you not just as a causative which means that you caused for something to be done.

Examples:

> 1.She was having her wall being painted.
>   2.She was having her wall be painted.
>   3.She was having her wall painted.
>   4.She had her wall being painted.
>   5.She had her wall painted.
>   6.She had her wall be painted.

Are they all correct and are there any differences regarding them being a continuous action or a quick one?

> 1.She was having herself being operated.
>   2.She was having herself be operated.
>   3.She had herself be operated.
>   4.She was having herself operated.
>   5.She had herself operated.
>   6.She had herself being operated.

Same for these what are the differences? And please let me know if any of these are incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The construction with causative *HAVE* <sup>†</sup> is

> *HAVE DirectObject VERBen* <sup>‡</sup>

There is no form of *BE* involved; the passive sense is conveyed by the past participle.

Consequently, in your first set of sentences, with *PAINT*, only ## 3 and 5 are correct.

> 3.She was having her wall painted.
>   5.She had her wall painted.

In your second set, with *OPERATE*, ## 4 and 5 would be correct, but the idiom is incorrect. We do not say that a surgeon *operates a patient* but that a surgeon *operates **on** a patient*. By the same token, we do not say that *a patient is operated* but that *a patient is operated **on***. **On** is a necessary part of the idiom. Consequently, the correct forms are:

> 4.She was having herself operated **on**.
>   5.She had herself operated **on**.

In both sets, the difference between the constructions with the past simple and past progressive forms of *HAVE* is the same as in any other use of these constructions: the simple form signifies a completed action (perfective aspect), the progressive action signifies an action in progress (imperfective aspect). See our tag-wiki on [Aspect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info).

---

<sup>†</sup> A verb in italic capitals signifies ‘any appropriate form or construction of the verb’
<sup>‡</sup> *VERBen* signifies ‘the past participle of the verb you are using’

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, you have been very helpful.