# The meaning and role of "have" in "Are you prepared to bear the risks but have the seller ogranize the transportation?"

Tags: causative-have

> Are you prepared to bear the risks during transportation but ***have*** the
>   seller ***organise*** and **pay** for transportation to the agreed place?

What is the role of "have" in this sentence? I do not understand meaning of the second part of the sentence because of it. To which part of the sentence "organise" refers?

Why "**organise**" does not take "**s**" if it refers to "**seller**"?

Comment: Replace *but* with *or*. You'll 'have' the meaning of 'have' then!

Comment: It is same as original text. Is it wrong?

Comment: I think it's [anything] but [anything] - a style. But not sure. What's the source? Any link? It'd give a better idea

Comment: Organize and not organizes because here, 'have' works like 'let'. It's not the seller doing things directly (for what it'd take 's). However, in such construction, I'd prefer using *-ing*. *"....transportation but have the seller organizing and paying for ...."*

Comment: No, I do not have whole of the book: just two pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are you prepared to bear the risks during transportation but **have** the seller **organise** and **pay** for transportation to the agreed place?

According to this proposal, if anything happens during the transportation, you will bear the risks.

However, it will not be you who will cover the transportation costs. It will be the seller. It will also be the seller who will organize the transportation.

You will only bear costs if anything happens to the cargo on its route.

I'm not totally sure I understand the meaning of this on a semantic level, but that's how it looks to me.

---

> Why "organise" does not take "s" if it refers to "seller"?

"To **have** someone **do** something" is a construction that means roughly to **cause** someone to do something, to **make** someone do something. Or, closer to your case, to "give someone the responsibility of doing something":

> [From Englishpage.com](http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/let.html):
>
> This construction means "to give someone the responsibility to do something."
>
> Examples:
>
> Dr. Smith **had** his nurse **take** the patient's temperature.
> Please **have** your secretary **fax** me the information.
> I **had** the mechanic **check** the brakes.

In your case, you could give the seller the responsibility to **organize** and **pay** for the transportation.

---

Related:

- [Snailboat's answer regarding **make-, have-,** and **let-** causatives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/37220/2127)
- [StoneyB's answer that mentions the **causative have**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/32810/2127)
- [Another answer by StoneyB on **causative have**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/22896/2127)
- [Another interesting discussion of the use of **causative have**, and again with StoneyB's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23677/about-causative-form)
- [A discussion of **causative have** at ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88158/causative-verb-using-have-has)

Comment: +1 Nice answer! I just hope to see ***have** the seller **organise** and **pay*** highlighted for the OP. ;-)